# A monotone matrix is nonsingular?

Tags: matrices

A monotone matrix is nonsingular.

According to Wikipedia, a proof of this is...

Let $A$ be a monotone matrix and assume there exists $x\neq0$ with $Ax=0$. Then, by monotonicity, $x\ge 0$ and $-x\ge 0$, and hence $x=0$.

1)When it says "assume that there exists $x\neq0$ with $Ax=0$", does it mean that it assumes $A$ is singular, and therefore $dim(ker(A))>0$ ?

2)I don't understand what the proof wants to say when it says "by monotonicity, $x\ge 0$ and $-x\ge 0$". From this why can you make a conclusion that it's proved?

Thanks!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: My apologies Clement, thank you very much for your help. Thanks to you now I figured this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. The proof is by contradiction: you assume $A$ is singular, pick $x\in\mathrm{ker} A\setminus \{0\}$ (which exists by your assumption $A$ is singular), and then use monotonicity of $A$ to show the contradiction: mnamely, that the $x$ you picked must be $0$, contradicting the way you chose it.
   *(Here, a proof by contradiction is actually unnecessary: a direct proof showing that any $x\in\mathrm{ker} A$ is $0$ would work as well).*
2. To see how monotonicity of $A$ is used: montonicity means

   > every vector $u$ such that $Au\geq 0$ must be such that $u \geq 0$

   where $\geq$ is entry-wise.

   For the vector $x$ that was picked, we have $Ax=0$ and $A(-x)=-Ax=-0=0$, so in particular $Ax\geq 0$ and $A(-x)\geq 0$. The monotonicity of $A$ then implies $x\geq 0$ and $-x\geq 0$.

   But then, this implies in turn $x\geq 0$ and $x\leq -0=0$, so every entry of $x$ satisfies $0\leq x_i \leq 0$: so every entry of $x$ is $0$, so $x$ is the $0$ vector.